# Status of Spark Job running on Amazon EMR in RESTful way

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I have idea of doing the same with cli in following way:

```
yarn application --status <app-id>
```

I want to know the status of Spark job running in EMR cluster in RESTful way.Is there any utility or How can i achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into yarn resource manager ui or spark history server.

```
Resource manager -> <master ip>:8088/cluster
Spark history server -> <master ip>:18080/history/application_1530774461344_0005/jobs/
Running spark application -> <master ip>:20888/proxy/application_1530774461344_0006/jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

There are:

- [REST
  API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api)
  for the running Spark application
- or
  [metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics)
  available for collection and observation